# User rate limits and service accounts for Google APIs

Tags: google-api-client, google-admin-sdk, service-accounts

Are the user rate limits applied when using service accounts with delegated users requests to Google APIs?

Answer (score 0):

I think the limits here in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/limits#api-limits-and-quotas) is applicable for both the service account and user account. You can check here the API limits, API quotas and other type of limits. Also, another way to check the limits of API is in the [Developers console](https://pantheon.corp.google.com) itself under the Quotas tab in each API.